# Java Program that takes a paragraph as input from user and prints number of delimiters (like \n, space, etc) on to the console

Tags: java

Please help me out as i am not understanding how to count the space, new line etc.  i understand how to count the lines and words using space delimiter. how do i print the count of space, tab, \n etc?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TextFileInfoPrinter
{  
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException        
    { 
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);           

        System.out.println("File to be read: ");
        String inputFile = console.next();

        File file = new File(inputFile);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

    int words = 0;
        int lines = 0;
        int chars = 0;

    while(in.hasNextLine())  {
            lines++;
            String line = in.nextLine();
            for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
            {
                if(line.charAt(i)!=' ' && line.charAt(i)!='\n')
                chars ++;
            }
            words += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();
    }


 System.out.println("Number of lines: " + lines);
 System.out.println("Number of words: " + words);
 System.out.println("Number of characters: " + chars);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `while` loop to this:

```
while(in.hasNextLine())  {
            lines++;
            String line = in.nextLine();
            for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
            {
                if(line.charAt(i)!=' ' && line.charAt(i)!='\n')
                    chars ++;
                else if (line.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                     spaces++;
                }
            }
            words += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();
    }
```

You just have to check if the `ith` character is equal to  like you check if in the previous `if`. And about lines you are already counting them well cause you are reading line by line from your file.

Answer (score 0):

Declare 2 new variables :

```
int spaces = 0;
int lineBreaks = 0;
```

Add following code inside for loop

```
if(line.charAt(i)==' ') {
                spaces ++;
            }
if(line.charAt(i)=='\n') {
                lineBreaks ++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following two solutions that can be used to take input paragraph.

```
// using scanner
import scanner

Scanner object = new Scanner(System.in);
string input = object.nextLine();

// using dataInputStream
DataInputStream object = new DataInputStram(System.in);
string input = object.readLine();
```